# Why is application.html.erb being called on a js response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails app I have a Ajax call to update a property:

```
def add_properties
    @conversation = Conversation.update(params[:conversationId], :points=> => params[:conversation][:points])

    respond_to do |format|
       format.js { render :partial => "add_properties" }
    end
end
```

And my _add_properties.js.erb is simple:

```
$('#ajaxFeedback').html('Property updated').show().fadeOut(4000);
```

What I am finding is that the call to the partial is choking due to some JQuery UI declarations in my application.html.erb.  When I remove the declarations, all works well.  How can I simply render the partial *without calling the application.html.erb*?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried?

`format.js { render :layout => false, :partial => "add_properties" }`

Comment: Thanks kobaltz, I really thought the render property would do the trick, but after adding, it still tried to use the application.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

Why not just rename that to `add_properties.js.erb`

call

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

Comment: Thanks Niko, but I can't have format.html since it's just a js response I want, but even if I rename and use format.js it's the same issue.